# What is proper replacement for React.ChildrenArray in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, flowtype

Why does the following react-native code give typescript error?

```
type ContainerProps = BaseProps & {
    children: React.ChildrenArray<React.ReactElement<any>>;
    withGutter?: boolean;
};
```

any
Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ChildrenArray'.ts(2694)

What is the correct expression instead?  This was originally flow based js code being converted to typescript...

Comment: Did you try: `React.ReactNode`?

Answer (score 0):

**React.Node**

This represents any node that can be rendered in a React application. `React.Node` can be null, a boolean, a number, a string, a `React element`, or an array of any of those types recursively.

If you need a return type for your component render() methods then you should use `React.Node`.

Usage

```js
type Node = React.ChildrenArray<void | null | boolean | string | number | React.Element<any>>;

type ContainerProps = BaseProps & {
    children: React.Node
    withGutter?: boolean;
};
```